# When to use machine epsilon and when not to?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a book about rendering 3d graphics and the author sometimes uses epsilon and sometimes doesn't.

[image]

Notice the `if` at the beginning using epsilon and the other `if`s that don't.

What's the logic behind this? I can see he avoids any chance for division by zero but when not using epsilon in the function there's still a chance it will return a value that will make the outer code to divide by zero.

Book is Real-Time Rendering 3rd Edition, by the way.

Comment: "...but when **not** using epsilon in the function there's still a chance it will return a value that will make the outer code to divide by zero." Isn't that a reason to use it?

Comment: It is. That's what I'm saying. However, the author doesn't do that. Notice the other `if` statements don't use epsilon.

Comment: Ok, I thought you meant when you removed the comparison to epsilon in the first statement.

Comment: Another use for this conditional might be avoiding unnecessary calculations. If value `f` is small (and probably don't contribute much into your final image, so you don't care), you avoid a whole bunch of FP operations (including terribly slow divisions) and branches. Is this from raytraycer or something?

Comment: It's a ray-OBB intersection test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first statement, `if(|f| > ϵ)` is just checking to make sure `f` is significantly different from 0. It's important to do that in that specific spot in the code because the next two statements divide by `f`.

The other statements don't need to do that, so they don't need to use `ϵ`.

For example,

```
if(t1 > t2) swap(t1, t2);
```

is a self-contained statement that compares two numbers to each other and swaps them if the wrong one is greater. Since it's not comparing to see if a value is close to 0, there's no need to use `ϵ`.

If the value that is returned from this block of code can make the calling code divide by zero, that should be handled in the calling code.

Comment: So epsilons should be used only when there might be a division by zero _in the local scope_?

Comment: @Pilpel It's kind of two different problems. One is that epsilon can be used to avoid division by zero. The other is that problems like division by zero should be handled in the proper scope. You want to write this function so it returns whatever is calculated, then handle division by zero in the caller if it is going to use that return value as a denominator.

Comment: @Pilpel To put it another way, I don't know what the caller of this code is going to do with the return value, so I don't need to worry about division by zero here. Some functions that call this might not be using it to divide at all. If others are, let them handle it.

Comment: I see. Thanks! If you could answer a little side question: say `a` and `b` are floats, and `if(b <= a)` passes, is `sqrt(a-b)` a safe operation or do I need epsilon here?

Comment: @Pilpel Since `a-b` is guaranteed to be non-negative, that should be safe.